# Import JS in another JS File

Tags: javascript, import

I try to split my giant JS file into little parts and import them, but it seems like the import doesnt work and idk why.

My folder structure:

```
-> index.html
-> js
   -> wonderbuild.js
   -> start.js
```

index.html

```html
<body>
<!-- content -->
<script src="js/wonderbuild.js"></script>
<body>
```

wonderbuild.js

```js
import {start} from './start.js';

window.onload = function() {
 start();
}
```

start.js

```js
export function start() {
    document.getElementById("loading-circle").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("welcome-message").style.opacity = "1";
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("loading-screen").style.opacity = "0";
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById("body").style.overflowY = "visible";
            document.getElementById("loading-screen").style.display = "none";
        }, 500);
    }, 4000);
}
```

When im not import this function, all works fine.
Anybody have an idea to fix this?

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: You need to set your script to `type="module"` to be able to start using `import` and `export`

Comment: @Reyno oh, that works. Thanks for the fast answer <3